# How to Auto click the button after typing the ID number to textbox (Visual Studio C#)

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

[image: i want to auto click the search button]

Search button >>>

i want the button to auto click after entering the school ID of textbox

Comment: How is the input supposed to know when you are done typing? Has the id always the same length?

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?

Comment: yes same length   here the sample video https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Nlb8NoVbkF4VjsNSqfqnjfvNWcyRU28D/view?usp=share_link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should first determine how you want to detect the ID has entered. then you should add a handler to that event to call the search button click handler .
for example if you want to do the search after user pressed the 'Enter' key, add a handler to 'KeyPress' envent of the School ID text box and call the search button's click event handler if the key is 'Enter' key:

```
      private void SchoolID_keypressed(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
      {
         if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.Enter))
            Search_Click(sender, EventArgs.Empty);
      }
```

P.S.: I assumed you are developing WinForm application

Comment: it works but how to really Auto enter after i entered the school ID without pressing the enter keyboard, i developed a Barcode Scanning using mobile camera to textbox automatic

Comment: @JustineLouiseVilla you may use 'TextChanged' event instead and check the length of the text in the School ID textbox

Comment: sorry for asking where is the variable of "keyChar" when i change the event to text changed it turns red

Comment: you don't need that if condition anymore! the "TextChanged" event will fire up whenever there is a change in the textbox. So, when the handler is called you need to check if the School ID is completely entered into the textbox: `if (SchoolId.Text.Length == 10) { SearchClick(...); }`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using keyboard events.

1. Receive input from the keyboard. Find the workspace that receives keyboard input. For example, in the default form form1, right-click into the property and set keypreview to true. If not set to true, the default is false and cannot receive keyboard input.

   [image]
2. Design UI as shown below. The textbox binds the keyboard event to trigger the click of the serarch button.

   [image]
   [image]
3. Code logic: input data in the text box -> press the space bar -> the event triggers the click of the button button.

   ```
    private void FrmLogin_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        School.UID = textBox1.Text;
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space) // press the space bar
        {
           if(School.UID == "20191097")
            {
                this.button1.PerformClick();

            }

        }


    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello: " + School.UID);
    }

     internal class School
   {
        public static string UID = "";
   }
   ```

Test code:

[image]